# Call to undefined method Bllim\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::package()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I followed these instructions ( https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package ) while setting up bllim datatables. but when I execute

```
php artisan config:publish bllim/datatables
```

I get this error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                         
Call to undefined method Bllim\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::package()
```

Any suggestions on how I should solve this

Comment: This is a version 4 package, so it won't work on your Laravel 5.

Comment: At the top of the readme is says the actively maintained package is this https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables.